# Using Python's exec() function with formatted string?

Tags: python, list, exec

I have a file containing my school schedule and I want to create a list from every line in the file. The file looks something like this:

```
first:second:third:fourth:fifth
first:second:third:fourth:fifth
```

The code is this:

```
schedule_file = "school-schedule.txt"
with open(schedule_file) as schedule:
    for c, line in enumerate(schedule):
        exec("ln%s = schedule.read().split(':')" % str(c+1))

print(ln1)
print(ln2)
print(ln3)
print(ln4)
print(ln5)
print(ln6)
print(ln7)
print(ln8)
print(ln9)
print(ln10)
```

I know that the file has ten lines, which is why, for testing purposes, I wanted it to print those ten lists. Unfortunately, it seems to put the the first line into the list called `ln1`and raises a NameError exception for all other lists, starting with `ln2`:

```
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\schedule.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(ln2)
NameError: name 'ln2' is not defined
```

Is it not possible to use formatted strings inside the `exec()` function or am I making some other stupid mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is in using `exec()`. Avoid it at all costs. Instead of trying to dynamically make 10 variables, just use a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for c, line in enumerate(schedule):
    exec("ln%s = schedule.read().split(':')" % str(c+1))
```

The line from the file is in the variable `line`, yet you wrote:

```
exec("ln%s = schedule.read().split(':')....
```

instead of:

```
exec("ln%s = line.split(':')...
```

In any case, whenever you find yourself writing variables with names like this:

```
print(ln1)
print(ln2)
print(ln3)
print(ln4)
```

where the variable names differ by only a number, then you need to STOP what you are doing, and use a list instead.  If you have a list named `ln`, then the items in the list already have the names `ln[0], ln[1]`, etc.  So, you can do this:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
      ln = [line.rstrip().split(':') for line in f]

print(ln)
print(ln[0])
print(ln[1])

--output:--
$ cat data.txt
a:b:c:d
e:f:g:h

$ python prog.py
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Thank you, too. As I said under the first answer, I'm not sure why I wanted ten variables for this. Using a list is much easier and definitely more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You have read the whole file after the first iteration so you never get past the first  `exec("ln%s =  .....`:

```
exec("ln%s = schedule.read().split(':')" % str(c+1))
                      ^^^
                     .read() # reads whole/rest of file
```

Just use readlines and access by index:

```
with open(schedule_file) as schedule:
    data = schedule.readlines()
ln1 = data[0].split(":")
.....
```

Or combine with map to split:

```
data = list(map(lambda x: x.split(":"),schedule))
```

You can also use a dict but it is not really going to be of anymore benefit than simply using a list and accessing by index.

If you really want ten variables then unpack:

```
 with open(schedule_file) as schedule:
    ln1,ln2 ....ln10 = map(lambda x: x.split(":"),schedule
```

Comment: Thanks. Using readlines and accessing by index is much easier than what I had in mind. Got a lot to learn :)
Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, first time for everything :)